# Virtuemart - Module featured products

Tags: module, product, virtuemart

I have marked my discounted products as "special" (featured). This offers are displayed in "Featured products". Ok.

Now, This module display:

- image
- description
- price

But how I can display price before to apply discount? Which files I need to edit to display this field?

Because I need to display price before discount with line-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, Virtuemart already has a built-in function that does this.

If you're looking for this:

[image: Display]

Simply find the Product, type in the amount plus the discount amount. Like so:

[image: Settings]

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but just let me know if you have any questions.